# Autofit splash screen image

Tags: android, splash-screen

This is the code i use in "activity_splash_screen.xml" file.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0099cc"
tools:context="com.taleshi.fartal.Activities.SplashScreenActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

And this is my app.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.taleshi.fartal

I have added **1280x1920, 960x1600, 720x1280, 480x800 and 320x480** splashscreen images to the splashscreen folder. I'm not sure why the image is not auto-fitted into different devices! It looks strang on my sony device, but look good on the virtual device "Nexus 5X API 26" in the Android Studio!

What is the fix here. Appriciate any help.
Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried out other `scaleType`s ?

Comment: Yea! But none gave a good solution...either the size of images is wrong or the type of scaletype not correct. Why is this so difficult! Isn't there any standard case that suits every android mobile device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the following folders under the res folder in your project directory:

drawable-mdpi 
drawable-hdpi 
drawable-xhdpi 
drawable-xxhdpi 
drawable-xxxhdpi 
put the 320 x 480 image under the drawable-mdpi folder 
put the 480 x 800 image under the drawable-hdpi folder 
put the 720 x 1280 image under the drawable-xhdpi folder 
put the 960 x 1600 image under the drawable-xxhdpi folder 
put the 1280 x 1920 image under the drawable-xxxhdpi folder 
next, rename all the images to have the same file name and then rerun your app.

Comment: what about this code "android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"" doesn't this mean that app get the splashscreen only from the drawable folder?

Comment: you are right in a way. but what android actually does, after you have created all the drawables folder, is it automatically select the image that that matches the screen size of the device your app is being run since each drawable folder corresponds to a particular screen resolution or screen density. And about the scale type dont use any scaling.

Comment: I have now updated my app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.taleshi.fartal) and it looks good now. For the display i have i did use "android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>" If i remove the scale type, then image do not cover the whole screen :( ... so i guess that "centerCrop" is my fix for now. i'm not sure about other devices like samsung galaxy, but on my sony xperia it looks good.